# While creating Change request and New Feature in Redmine, Target Version must be auto-filled and must be Read only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redmine

I have one new requirement in Redmine.

While creating CR/NF,Target Version must be auto-filled with a particular target version(Ex:Sprint 1) and It must also be read only.How can I do this requirement Please suggest me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the "read only" only by setting the priviledges for the user/group the user, who opens the CR/NF, at the `workflow/persmissions` admin option - select `field permissions`there.

A default target version can't be set by default redmine. There exists a [feature request](http://www.redmine.org/issues/1828) for that since several years but it has not been implemented yet. But there is a [plugin](https://github.com/benasher44/redmine_default_version)  available on which claims to offer this feature.

Comment: I have installed that plugin..But there is nothing changed.can we Set default version to a particular tracker in redmine?

Comment: I don't use the plugin myself so I can't tell you how it works. But you can try to open an issue on their github page.